# Substring file path

Tags: c#, dictionary, substring

Hi I'm trying to substring a file path before it goes into a dictionary. I've tried to declare the start point but am given an error:

**StartIndex cannot be larger than length of string. Parameter name: startIndex**

This is my code

```
private  Dictionary<string,int> CreateDictionary(log logInstance)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            for (int entryIdex = 0; entryIdex < logInstance.logentry.Count(); entryIdex++)
            {
                logLogentry entry = logInstance.logentry[entryIdex];
                for (int pathIdex = 0; pathIdex < entry.paths.Count(); pathIdex++)
                {
                    logLogentryPath path = entry.paths[pathIdex];
                    string filePath = path.Value;
                    filePath.Substring(63);
                    string cutPath = filePath;
                    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(cutPath))
                    {
                        dictionary[cutPath]++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dictionary.Add(cutPath, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            return dictionary;
        }
```

Any help would be great.

I've also tried doing

```
filePath.Substring(0, 63);
```

and

```
filePath.Substring(63, length);
```

Comment: You don't assign the returned string from `filePath.Substring(63)` to any  variable, why? However, that overload gives you the part behind the 63th character, so the string must be at least 63 characters long. What do you actually want?

Comment: The string is 81 characters long

Comment: Can you debug it and check for sure? The error seems to indicate that the string is less than 63 characters. Also, I think that this: `filePath.Substring(63); string cutPath = filePath;` needs to be replaced with `string curPath = filePath.Substring(63);`.

Comment: @npinit When I debug it in the filePath this is what is show "/GEM4/trunk/src/Tools/TaxMarkerUpdateTool/Tax Marker Ripper v1/Help_Document.docx"

Comment: What does the *magic number* **63** stand for? What *actually* you're going to achiev?

Comment: 63 is the character I was to substring from the file path for every entry looks like this: /GEM4/trunk/src/Tools/TaxMarkerUpdateTool/Tax Marker Ripper v1 with the final bit the real information i want to be shown which is: /DataModifier.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in C# are immutable (once a string is created it cannot be modified), this means that when you set `string cutpath = filepath` you are setting the value of `cutpath` to `path.Value` as you haven't assigned the value of `filepath.SubString(63)` to anything. To fix this change

```
string filePath = path.Value;
filePath.Substring(63); // here is the problem
string cutPath = filePath;
```

To

```
string filePath = path.Value;
string cutPath = filePath.Substring(63);
```

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
// It's do nothing
filePath.Substring(63);

// Change to this
filePath = filePath.Substring(63);
```

Second:

> 63 is the character I was to substring from the file path for every
>   entry looks like this: /GEM4/trunk/src/Tools/TaxMarkerUpdateTool/Tax
>   Marker Ripper v1 with the final bit the real information i want to be
>   shown which is: /DataModifier.cs

It's a bad idea to use 63. Better find last "/" and save it position to some variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone for the help

My code now works and looks like this:

```
Private  Dictionary<string,int> CreateDictionary(log logInstance)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int entryIdex = 0; entryIdex < logInstance.logentry.Count(); entryIdex++)
        {
            logLogentry entry = logInstance.logentry[entryIdex];
            for (int pathIdex = 0; pathIdex < entry.paths.Count(); pathIdex++)
            {
                logLogentryPath path = entry.paths[pathIdex];
                string filePath = path.Value;

                if (filePath.Length > 63)
                {
                    string cutPath = filePath.Substring(63);
                    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(cutPath))
                    {
                        dictionary[cutPath]++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dictionary.Add(cutPath, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comments, it appears you simply want the file name from the file path. There is a built in utility for achieving this on any path.

From MSDN:

> **Path.GetFileName**
>
> Returns the file name and extension of the specified path string.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Here is a code sample to get you started.

```
string path = @"/GEM4/trunk/src/Tools/TaxMarkerUpdateTool/Tax Marker Ripper v1/Help_Document.docx";

string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFilename(path);

Console.WriteLine(filename);
```

**Output**

> Help_Document.docx

And here is your code with the modification;

```
Private  Dictionary<string,int> CreateDictionary(log logInstance)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int entryIdex = 0; entryIdex < logInstance.logentry.Count(); entryIdex++)
        {
            logLogentry entry = logInstance.logentry[entryIdex];
            for (int pathIdex = 0; pathIdex < entry.paths.Count(); pathIdex++)
            {
                logLogentryPath path = entry.paths[pathIdex];
                string filePath = path.Value;

                // extract the file name from the path
                string cutPath = System.IO.Path.GetFilename(filePath);

                if (dictionary.ContainsKey(cutPath))
                {
                    dictionary[cutPath]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    dictionary.Add(cutPath, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
```